# insert figure in sweave using knitr fig.path

Tags: r, sweave, knitr

I'm trying to insert a figure using Sweave which is located in the path `C:\Users\eccehomo\Documents\mi\fig1.png`. I'm using the package `knitr`which has a function  called `fig.path`but I'm getting many errors for such a simple thing! Here's one of the things I have tried:

```
<<fig1,fig=TRUE>>=
library(knitr)
f='C:/Users/eccehomo/Documents/mi/fig1.png'
@

\includegraphics{f}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\includegraphics{\Sexpr{f}}`. LaTeX does not know the variables in R.