# insert figure in sweave using knitr fig.path Version 2

Tags: r, sweave, knitr

I have a question similar to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116967/insert-figure-in-sweave-using-knitr-fig-path).

I am trying to add a `.jpg` to a `.Rnw` file (compiling LaTex with RSweave and knitr). I've tried the following without success:

```
<<IMAG0387.jpg,fig=TRUE>>=
library(knitr)
f <- 'M:/QW Monitoring Team/GLRI toxics/Phase II/Wastewater Intensive/Sniffer/Leaf_Experiments/photos/IMAG0387.jpg'
@
\includegraphics{f}
```

I'm getting an error:

```
You can now run (pdf)latex on 'Sam_Report_Actual.tex'
Warning message:
file stem 'Sam_Report_Actual-IMAG0387.jpg' is not portable 
Running pdflatex.exe on Sam_Report_Actual.tex...failed
```

Note that `Sam_Report_Actual` is the name of the `.Rnw` file.  I've checked `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin` on my coputer and I have pdflatex.exe so I'm not sure what's going on. Suggestions?

Comment: Hay you tried the solution of the linked post? Test it with files and directories without any space or special character.

Comment: useful suggestion - but that doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh, since you have read the post that you linked to, why did you still write `\includegraphics{f}` (which is apparently wrong according to the answer to that post)?

Please post the full error message (presumably in `Sam_Report_Actual.log`), and avoid using absolute paths (always use relative paths if possible) and spaces in file paths (use `_` or `-` instead).

Comment: Fixing the file path, that is, eliminating the use of _ and - in conjunction with the use of \includegraphics{\Sexpr{f}} helped solve the problem.